# Is it possible to hide classes from ui tests

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I have a few helper classes like `UnlockedTestCase` that configure my app for special scenario tests.

Theses classes show up in the test navigator without tests.

Is there a way to mark then as "not test classes" in order for them to be ignored by the test navigator?

**UPDATE:** Sample code:

```
class UnlockedTestCase: XCTestCase {
    var app = XCUIApplication()

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        continueAfterFailure = false

        app.launchArguments = ["uiTesting", "unlock"]
        app.launch()
    }
}
```

A test would then be written as:

```
class UnlockedUITests: UnlockedTestCase {
    func testButton() {
        XCTAssers(app.buttons["SomeButtonInTheUnlockedState"].exists)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the following structure:

```
MyTestHelperClassName: XCTestCase {
    //... your helper methods
}
```

Remove its subclass declaration of `XCTestCase`
i.e the `: XCTestCase` part

Then it will not appear in the "Test Navigator"

Comment: I need it to be inheriting from `XCTestCase`, because the test classes then will be defined like: `class randomTestClass: UnlockedTestCase` and they have code in the `setUp` function, is there any other way?

Comment: @Daniel Update your question with sample code so we can cut to the chase and find a solution.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry, couldn't find a solution for this case. But you can disable the class or even individual tests from the right-click menu in `Test Navigator`. It won't affect the tests though.

Comment: @Daniel The thing is, you want a common `setUp()` so it has to subclass `XCTestCase` and in that case, it __will__ show up in the test navigator. If it were only helper functions, this answer works. But anyways, will still keep a look out for a solution :)

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not a way to exclude that kind of class from the test navigator without losing the ease of defining the `setUp()`, as the way that it discovers test case classes is simplistic, and from the point of view of the navigator, you could add test cases to the parent/helper class at any moment since it is an `XCTestCase` descendant.

There is no protocol for 'helper' or 'abstract-only' classes which support inheritance in the way that you require, since inheritance from XCTestCase is required for the automatic discovery and usage of tests and test hooks like `setUp()`.

If you *really* want to get rid of your helper entities from the test navigator, you could abstract them into protocols with extensions `where Self: XCTestCase` (to allow you access to XCTestCase's interface in the extension), have your test class conform to them, and override `setUp()` in the class where your tests are.

```
protocol UnlockableTest {}
extension UnlockableTest where Self: XCTestCase {
    func unlockSetUp() {
        continueAfterFailure = false

        app.launchArguments = ["uiTesting", "unlock"]
        app.launch()
    }
}

class UnlockedUITests: XCTestCase, UnlockableTest {
    var app = XCUIApplication()

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()

        unlockSetUp()
    }

    func testButton() {
        XCTAssert(app.buttons["SomeButtonInTheUnlockedState"].exists)
    }
}
```

However, I think the simplicity and convenience of your current approach is the preferable compromise. Protocols also can't contain stored properties though, so in order to get the benefit of a stored property, you'd need to add the `app` property to every `XCTestCase` descendant too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Swift packages now, if your tests are in a Swift Package then you can have a helper module that contains your base classes and these will not be added to the sidebar as empty test cases.

You can mix an xcodeproj with a local to the source folder swift package to facilitate this, and in general I would personally recommend this as it improves build times and allows you to make your codebase more modular with granular access control.